# How can I improve performance of Order By clause in Oracle

Tags: oracle, database-design, performance, order-by, query-performance

I have a table called `UAVT_BINA` in oracle database and it have 28897352 rows. When I write:

```
select * from UAVT_BINA
```

the DB responds to me in 0.1 second. But when I write

```
select * from UAVT_BINA order by CBSBMKODU
```

the DB responds to me in 66 second.
I have a index on `CSBMKODU` . I have to sort the data due to the application standards
How can I improve performance, can anyone help me ?

Here is the result of explain plan for sorted query

[image]

I have said before that we use a dynamic query on the framework side and the simple result query of the filtered data is here

```
SELECT 
"Project2"."C1" AS "C1", 
"Project2"."CRTM" AS "CRTM", 
"Project2"."ADANO" AS "ADANO", 
"Project2"."BINADURUMSTRING" AS "BINADURUMSTRING", 
"Project2"."C2" AS "C2", 
"Project2"."BINANUMARATAJTIPISTRING" AS "BINANUMARATAJTIPISTRING", 
"Project2"."BINAYAPITIPISTRING" AS "BINAYAPITIPISTRING", 
"Project2"."BLOKADI" AS "BLOKADI", 
"Project2"."CSBMADI" AS "CSBMADI", 
"Project2"."C3" AS "C3", 
"Project2"."DISKAPINO" AS "DISKAPINO", 
"Project2"."C4" AS "C4", 
"Project2"."C5" AS "C5", 
"Project2"."C6" AS "C6", 
"Project2"."NITELIKSTRING" AS "NITELIKSTRING", 
"Project2"."C7" AS "C7", 
"Project2"."PAFTANO" AS "PAFTANO", 
"Project2"."PARSELNO" AS "PARSELNO", 
"Project2"."POSTAKODU" AS "POSTAKODU", 
"Project2"."SITEADI" AS "SITEADI", 
"Project2"."C8" AS "C8", 
"Project2"."C9" AS "C9", 
"Project2"."UPTRID" AS "UPTRID", 
"Project2"."UPTM" AS "UPTM", 
"Project2"."STATESTRING" AS "STATESTRING", 
"Project2"."STATEID" AS "STATEID", 
"Project2"."CRTRID" AS "CRTRID", 
"Project2"."MAHALLEADI" AS "MAHALLEADI", 
"Project2"."BINADURUMID" AS "BINADURUMID", 
"Project2"."BINANUMARATAJTIPIID" AS "BINANUMARATAJTIPIID", 
"Project2"."BINAYAPITIPIID" AS "BINAYAPITIPIID", 
"Project2"."MAHALLEID" AS "MAHALLEID"
FROM ( SELECT 
    "Distinct1"."DISKAPINO" AS "DISKAPINO", 
    "Distinct1"."SITEADI" AS "SITEADI", 
    "Distinct1"."BLOKADI" AS "BLOKADI", 
    "Distinct1"."POSTAKODU" AS "POSTAKODU", 
    "Distinct1"."CRTM" AS "CRTM", 
    "Distinct1"."CRTRID" AS "CRTRID", 
    "Distinct1"."UPTM" AS "UPTM", 
    "Distinct1"."UPTRID" AS "UPTRID", 
    "Distinct1"."STATEID" AS "STATEID", 
    "Distinct1"."STATESTRING" AS "STATESTRING", 
    "Distinct1"."ADANO" AS "ADANO", 
    "Distinct1"."PARSELNO" AS "PARSELNO", 
    "Distinct1"."PAFTANO" AS "PAFTANO", 
    "Distinct1"."BINADURUMSTRING" AS "BINADURUMSTRING", 
    "Distinct1"."BINADURUMID" AS "BINADURUMID", 
    "Distinct1"."BINAYAPITIPIID" AS "BINAYAPITIPIID", 
    "Distinct1"."BINAYAPITIPISTRING" AS "BINAYAPITIPISTRING", 
    "Distinct1"."BINANUMARATAJTIPIID" AS "BINANUMARATAJTIPIID", 
    "Distinct1"."BINANUMARATAJTIPISTRING" AS "BINANUMARATAJTIPISTRING", 
    "Distinct1"."NITELIKSTRING" AS "NITELIKSTRING", 
    "Distinct1"."CSBMADI" AS "CSBMADI", 
    "Distinct1"."MAHALLEID" AS "MAHALLEID", 
    "Distinct1"."MAHALLEADI" AS "MAHALLEADI", 
    1 AS "C1", 
     CAST( "Distinct1"."BINANO" AS number(19,0)) AS "C2", 
     CAST( "Distinct1"."CSBMID" AS number(19,0)) AS "C3", 
     CAST( "Distinct1"."ESKIBINAKIMLIKNO" AS number(19,0)) AS "C4", 
     CAST( "Distinct1"."ESKIBINAKODU" AS number(19,0)) AS "C5", 
     CAST( "Distinct1"."ID" AS number(19,0)) AS "C6", 
     CAST( "Distinct1"."NITELIKID" AS number(19,0)) AS "C7", 
     CAST( "Distinct1"."YOLALTIKATSAYISI" AS number(19,0)) AS "C8", 
     CAST( "Distinct1"."YOLUSTUKATSAYISI" AS number(19,0)) AS "C9"
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
        "Extent1"."ID" AS "ID", 
        "Extent1"."DISKAPINO" AS "DISKAPINO", 
        "Extent1"."SITEADI" AS "SITEADI", 
        "Extent1"."BLOKADI" AS "BLOKADI", 
        "Extent1"."POSTAKODU" AS "POSTAKODU", 
        "Extent1"."ESKIBINAKODU" AS "ESKIBINAKODU", 
        "Extent1"."CRTM" AS "CRTM", 
        "Extent1"."CRTRID" AS "CRTRID", 
        "Extent1"."UPTM" AS "UPTM", 
        "Extent1"."UPTRID" AS "UPTRID", 
        "Extent1"."STATEID" AS "STATEID", 
        "Extent1"."NITELIKID" AS "NITELIKID", 
        "Extent1"."STATESTRING" AS "STATESTRING", 
        "Extent1"."CSBMID" AS "CSBMID", 
        "Extent1"."ADANO" AS "ADANO", 
        "Extent1"."PARSELNO" AS "PARSELNO", 
        "Extent1"."PAFTANO" AS "PAFTANO", 
        "Extent1"."BINANO" AS "BINANO", 
        "Extent1"."YOLALTIKATSAYISI" AS "YOLALTIKATSAYISI", 
        "Extent1"."YOLUSTUKATSAYISI" AS "YOLUSTUKATSAYISI", 
        "Extent1"."ESKIBINAKIMLIKNO" AS "ESKIBINAKIMLIKNO", 
        "Extent1"."BINADURUMSTRING" AS "BINADURUMSTRING", 
        "Extent1"."BINADURUMID" AS "BINADURUMID", 
        "Extent1"."BINAYAPITIPIID" AS "BINAYAPITIPIID", 
        "Extent1"."BINAYAPITIPISTRING" AS "BINAYAPITIPISTRING", 
        "Extent1"."BINANUMARATAJTIPIID" AS "BINANUMARATAJTIPIID", 
        "Extent1"."BINANUMARATAJTIPISTRING" AS "BINANUMARATAJTIPISTRING", 
        "Extent1"."NITELIKSTRING" AS "NITELIKSTRING", 
        "Extent1"."CSBMADI" AS "CSBMADI", 
        "Extent1"."MAHALLEID" AS "MAHALLEID", 
        "Extent1"."MAHALLEADI" AS "MAHALLEADI"
        FROM  (SELECT 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."ID" AS "ID", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."DISKAPINO" AS "DISKAPINO", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."SITEADI" AS "SITEADI", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."BLOKADI" AS "BLOKADI", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."POSTAKODU" AS "POSTAKODU", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."ESKIBINAKODU" AS "ESKIBINAKODU", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."CRTM" AS "CRTM", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."CRTRID" AS "CRTRID", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."UPTM" AS "UPTM", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."UPTRID" AS "UPTRID", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."STATEID" AS "STATEID", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."NITELIKID" AS "NITELIKID", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."STATESTRING" AS "STATESTRING", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."CSBMID" AS "CSBMID", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."ADANO" AS "ADANO", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."PARSELNO" AS "PARSELNO", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."PAFTANO" AS "PAFTANO", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."BINANO" AS "BINANO", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."YOLALTIKATSAYISI" AS "YOLALTIKATSAYISI", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."YOLUSTUKATSAYISI" AS "YOLUSTUKATSAYISI", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."ESKIBINAKIMLIKNO" AS "ESKIBINAKIMLIKNO", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."BINADURUMSTRING" AS "BINADURUMSTRING", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."BINADURUMID" AS "BINADURUMID", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."BINAYAPITIPIID" AS "BINAYAPITIPIID", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."BINAYAPITIPISTRING" AS "BINAYAPITIPISTRING", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."BINANUMARATAJTIPIID" AS "BINANUMARATAJTIPIID", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."BINANUMARATAJTIPISTRING" AS "BINANUMARATAJTIPISTRING", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."NITELIKSTRING" AS "NITELIKSTRING", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."CSBMADI" AS "CSBMADI", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."MAHALLEID" AS "MAHALLEID", 
"UAVT_BINA_EVW"."MAHALLEADI" AS "MAHALLEADI"
FROM "ATLAS"."UAVT_BINA_EVW" "UAVT_BINA_EVW") "Extent1"
        INNER JOIN (SELECT 
"BS_AUTHORIZEDREGION_EVW"."ID" AS "ID", 
"BS_AUTHORIZEDREGION_EVW"."MAHALLEID" AS "MAHALLEID", 
"BS_AUTHORIZEDREGION_EVW"."KOYID" AS "KOYID", 
"BS_AUTHORIZEDREGION_EVW"."BUCAKID" AS "BUCAKID", 
"BS_AUTHORIZEDREGION_EVW"."ILCEID" AS "ILCEID", 
"BS_AUTHORIZEDREGION_EVW"."ROLEID" AS "ROLEID", 
"BS_AUTHORIZEDREGION_EVW"."USERID" AS "USERID",
"BS_AUTHORIZEDREGION_EVW"."ILID" AS "ILID",
"BS_AUTHORIZEDREGION_EVW"."ATUHORIZEDREGIONTYPEID" AS "ATUHORIZEDREGIONTYPEID"
FROM "ATLAS"."BS_AUTHORIZEDREGION_EVW" "BS_AUTHORIZEDREGION_EVW") "Extent2" ON (("Extent1"."MAHALLEID" = "Extent2"."MAHALLEID") OR (("Extent1"."MAHALLEID" IS NULL) AND ("Extent2"."MAHALLEID" IS NULL))) AND ((:p__linq__0 = "Extent2"."USERID") OR ((:p__linq__0 IS NULL) AND ("Extent2"."USERID" IS NULL)))
    )  "Distinct1"
)  "Project2"
ORDER BY "Project2"."CRTM" DESC
```

Comment: You need to include the index definition - if there is something wrong with that we can't tell without seeing it. Is it an index just on that column of an index that covers that column but not as the first one int he sort order? Also the query plan used in each case would use useful (you can get this ftom `EXPLAIN PLAN`, see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#i3305) - I suspect it is scanning then sorting in the second example but the plan will confirm that or illuminate otherwise.

Comment: You should ask this question to the one who is reponsible for this application standard. Are you sure that you want to do a `select *`? what if you want to manipulate the last record of this dataset? Does your application standard require that you fetch all of the 28897352 rows to get the last one?

Comment: answer for @miracle173 , First, we use the Entity Framework on the service side, and we create all sql queries. Client apps have grid components that can sort, page, filter data by column name, We crate Iquarable queries in framework for client side arguments and execute this query on oracle. We have to sort data because of pagination

Comment: @David Spillett I added explian plan result

Comment: The SQL needs all rows from the table so 'Oracle' will not use the index and do all processing 'in-memory'. If you want it to be faster you will need to limit the number of rows you want to fetch.

Comment: The easiest way to improve performance in this case is to select only those columns you want and filter only those rows you need and only then do an order by (if needed). ORDER BY requires all rows to be FETCHED before they can be ordered. Index is of no use in your case because you are selecting all rows and oracle will use a FTS.

Comment: @Raj, the way we are use is almost equalt to what you said . But the queries are taking too long because the number of aggregate entries is too high

Comment: @Marco (and Raj): Surely it would be able to use an appropriate index to read the rows in order, even if all the rows are returned, to avoid resorting in memory (or worse, potentially spooling to disk)? Unless it thinks the row lookups after scanning the index would be less efficient than a full table scan?

Comment: @MehmetEminYalçın - "I added explian plan result": though not the index/table definition also suggested.

Comment: @DavidSpillett, i think Oracle is ignoring index in this case because it is a single block read, whereas it can do FTS much more efficiently using multi-block reads. You can probably see this in event 10053 trace. Without a where clause (and proper stats) a FTS is almost always better in this regard. Now, you could employ parallel hint and see if it improves performance in this case.

Comment: Do you need to optimise this query in order to get the first rows back from it as soon as possible, or to get all rows back as soon as possible? If the former then you might benefit from an index-based `order by` at the expense of a longer total query time. If the latter then a full scan and sort is likely to be fastest, but it will take a while for the first rows to be returned.

Comment: @Raj "ORDER BY requires all rows to be FETCHED before they can be ordered." That's not 100% true -- an index might be used to both select the rows required *and* to determine the required order.

Comment: Thanks @DavidAldridge, I have not seen it but it may be possible.

Comment: @Raj - "i think Oracle is ignoring index in this case because it is a single block read": though we can't know for sure that is the reason as thus far the request to see the definition of the index has been ignored. I've know people assume that an index defined on `(col1, col2)` should help filtering/ordering by `col2` and that could also be the confusion here. The 0.1s-to-66s time difference implies to me that a full sort-on-disk is happening where an appropriate index should allow a more efficient "index scan followed by row lookup" plan? Though Oracle may differ from my MSSQL experience.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the query does not use the index. If it would use the index it would have to do the following:

- fetch the first entry of the index

  - lookup in the table  by rowid the other data of this row
- fetch the next entry of the index

  - lookup in the table  by rowid the other data of this row
- fetch the next entry of the index

  - lookup the other data that belong to this row from the table
- ...

This lookup of the data in the table is necessary because you have a `*` in your select clause. I assume that the index does not contain all the data of a row.  So if one fetches all the data of the

```
select *
from BINA
order by CBSBMKODU
```

statement then it is faster to avoid the index but to fetch all the data from the table and sort it. Fetching all the data and sort it takes 66 seconds. After this the first record can be sent to the client.

You can try to onvince your database to use the index anyway (I don't know if they will work)

use the session/system [parameter OPTIMIZER_MODE](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-DE448A8A-992F-4BAB-9302-A020039641E5.htm#REFRN10145) and set it to `FIRST_ROWS`. Then the database tries to minimize the time until the first row is fetched and therefore may use the index.

Use a [hint to guide the optimizer to the index](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements006.htm#BABEFDFC) to change your query to

```
select /*+ INDEX(BINA CBSBMKODU) */ *
from BINA
order by CBSBMKODU
```

Alternately, you could change the structure of your data:

You change your index CBSBMKODU so that it will contain all fields of a row.
Then the databae can retrieve all the values of a row from the index and does not have to look it up in the table. Therefore it may use the access by the index and dowes not try to scan the table. Note that, with this solution, you are storing two full copies of the table: once in the table itself, and again in the index CBSBMKODU.

Or, you could change the structure of the table and make it an [index organized table](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/tables.htm#ADMIN01506) instead of the usual heap organized table. Then the table is already organized like an index and you don't have to hold the data twice.

But all in all these solutions are not really satisfying. You should review these "application standards" with respect to the database. Clearly, it would be better not to be returning 30 million rows of pre-sorted data.

Answer (score 1):

When I try to extract the essence of this query I get this one:

```
SELECT Project2.*
FROM 
    (SELECT Distinct1.*
    FROM 
        (SELECT DISTINCT Extent1.*
        FROM (SELECT UAVT_BINA_EVW.* FROM ATLAS.UAVT_BINA_EVW UAVT_BINA_EVW) Extent1
            INNER JOIN (SELECT BS_AUTHORIZEDREGION_EVW.* FROM ATLAS.BS_AUTHORIZEDREGION_EVW BS_AUTHORIZEDREGION_EVW) Extent2 ON 
                ((Extent1.MAHALLEID = Extent2.MAHALLEID) 
                    OR ((Extent1.MAHALLEID IS NULL) AND (Extent2.MAHALLEID IS NULL))) 
                AND ((:p__linq__0 = Extent2.USERID) OR ((:p__linq__0 IS NULL) AND (Extent2.USERID IS NULL)))
        ) Distinct1
    ) Project2
ORDER BY Project2.CRTM DESC;
```

I don't see any reason for all these sub-queries. If I am not wrong this is equal to

```
SELECT DISTINCT ...
FROM ATLAS.UAVT_BINA_EVW UAVT_BINA_EVW Extent1
    INNER JOIN ATLAS.BS_AUTHORIZEDREGION_EVW Extent2 ON 
        ((Extent1.MAHALLEID = Extent2.MAHALLEID) 
            OR ((Extent1.MAHALLEID IS NULL) AND (Extent2.MAHALLEID IS NULL))) 
        AND ((:p__linq__0 = Extent2.USERID) OR ((:p__linq__0 IS NULL) AND (Extent2.USERID IS NULL)))
ORDER BY CRTM DESC;
```

`INNER JOIN ... ON ((Extent1.MAHALLEID = Extent2.MAHALLEID) 
                OR ((Extent1.MAHALLEID IS NULL) AND (Extent2.MAHALLEID IS NULL))`

looks like a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, so at the end you should be able to reduce the query to something similar as this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ...
FROM ATLAS.UAVT_BINA_EVW UAVT_BINA_EVW Extent1
    FULL OUTER JOIN ATLAS.BS_AUTHORIZEDREGION_EVW Extent2 ON Extent1.MAHALLEID = Extent2.MAHALLEID 
WHERE :p__linq__0 = Extent2.USERID OR (:p__linq__0 IS NULL AND Extent2.USERID IS NULL)
ORDER BY CRTM DESC;
```

You see, the only predicate is on `:p__linq__0 = Extent2.USERID` (usually you would write this as `Extent2.USERID = :p__linq__0` - do you have an index on `ATLAS.BS_AUTHORIZEDREGION_EVW.USERID`? This would be the only index which Oracle **may** use.

I think an index on CRTM does not help due to `DISTINCT` clause. This forces Oracle to read entire result and put into TEMP segment for sorting - but here I am not sure.

Comment: thank you first of all, ATLAS.BS_AUTHORIZEDREGION_EVW.USERID has a index but oracle doesn't use that unfortunetly , when I write your last query on oracle , it responded to me about 70 second :( , But you are right about simplified query